# Revealing Module Pattern problems

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Here's my code:

```
var APP = {}

APP.item = function() {
    var two = function() { return "three"; }
    return {
        two: two
    };
}

console.log(APP.item.two);
```

Now, from what I've read, shouldn't the output be "three"? Rather, the result is undefined.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mhxpz/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `item` and `two` are functions that need invoking:

```
console.log(APP.item().two());
```

...

**EXTRA EXPLANATORY NOTE:** In your original code, the `item` bit is just returning the function, not the object you want the function to return. Therefore when you ask for `item.two` it cannot find a `two` property (since that is part of the returned object, not part of the `item` function itself). Hope that makes sense of this for you.

Comment: @Namamyayg No problem. Please don't forget to mark correct if this worked for you ;-)

Comment: Definitely, just waiting for that 10 minute timer get over :S

Answer (score 2):

The result is undefined because you are not invoking the `APP.item` function (thus getting the `return` value. Also you will need to invoke the `two` function to get its return value:

```
console.log( APP.item().two() );  // outputs "three"
```